# Bread Board Power Supply

Tags: power, filter, bypass-capacitor

I am trying to clean up a source signal that has a lot of jitter between 3.7v+ and 5.6v+. I need a steady 5 volts with with a current of 1.2 amps minimum. The problem I face is that every-time I connect my circuit, the voltage drops to 3v+. I used ohms law to verify my circuits current requirements and I am meeting that with 2 amps. My circuit draws 1.2 amps. I am not sure if my source is total garbage or if I am doing something wrong! Any ideas on if a bypass capacitor will even help me?

The source is a 5v 2 amp usb cell phone charge hooked up to a OSEEP USB to DC Barrel Jack Connector plugged into a Breadboard PowerSupply ([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B010UJFVTU?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B010UJFVTU))

I don't have a Type A to Type A usb cable which is why I am using the barrel jack.

The load is a DHT11 connected to an ESP8266 (3.3v breadboard rails). and a Arduino Pro Mini 5v (5v breadboard rails). With pullup resistors and LEDS for debugging.

The ESP8266 is running its own core and the Pro Mini is being used as a debugger  and programmer as I don't trust connecting the ESP8266 directly to my computer even via an FTDI.

Still, my main problem is that the breadboard power supply is producing inconsistent voltages with my multimeter as the only load. Other than using wall warts, this is the first power supply I have ever used.

If I can find time I will Fritzing a Circuit Diagram for you. However, I am not sure how much help that could be since the problem is before the circuit is even  applied.

Comment: It would be helpful to include more information about the source and load (what are they?).

Comment: schematic would be best

Comment: Do not even bother with the silly "Fritzing" type circuit diagram. They are next to useless for communicating how a circuit works.

Comment: Could you just load the source with a resistor (e.g. 3.9 Ohms) to draw approximately the current your application would draw (make sure it can handle the power dissipation). Than observe the voltage drop while connecting and disconnecting the resistor. Also try to use an oscilloscope to monitor the voltage drop and its swing. A handheld multimeter might not be of much use (if not at least a true RMS type).

Comment: The linked "JBtek Breadboard Power Supply Module" is specified with max. 700 mA output current. Your 1,2 A drawn with the two loads might be a litte to much. Does each component (DHT11 + ESP8266 and Ardunio) alone work properly powered on the breadboard power supply?

Comment: @Stefan You are right about the output current of the breadboard power supply. That is the problem. So I decided to build my own power supply. After which, from learning by doing, I realized that since the breadboard power supply had to regulators for split voltage rails, if I turned off one rail I would receive 1.8 amps though the remaining rail. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AMS1117 5V linear regulator in that breadboard module has a dropout voltage of up to 1.3V at 800mA, and there is also a silicon diode in series with the power socket that drops another 0.7V. Therefore at best you will only get a little over 3V out of it.

To get the full 5V from your USB power supply you need to plug it into the USB port on the breadboard module!